# Vue.js child component not updated

Tags: vue.js

I have 3 vue.js nested components: main, parent, child.

The parent component load basic data, the child is a simple countdown widget which needs just a data to be configured.

If I set the parent script with static data (IE deadline='2019-12-12') the child show the widget working nice, but if I use dynamic data it generate error.

I'm using *computed* to pass data to the child component and if I debug it using an alert I see 2 alerts: *undefined* and then the correct date.

The issue is the first computed data (*undefined*) crash the widget, so how to create child component using updated (loaded) data?

**Parent template**:

```
<template>
   <div>
    <flip-countdown :deadline=deadline></flip-countdown>
   </div>
</template>
```

**Parent Script**: *it needs to be fixed*

```
export default {
    components: {FlipCountdown},

    props: ['event'],

    computed: {

        deadline: function () {
            if (typeof(this.event.date)!="undefined") {
                //alert(this.event.date)
                return this.event.date;
            } else {
                return "2019-05-21 00:00:00";
            }
        },
    },
```

**Child template**: *it works*

```
<template>
  <div>
      <flip-countdown :deadline="deadline"></flip-countdown>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Your parent template and child template look exactly the same, except that you forgot the double qoutes in `deadline=deadline` (should be `deadline="deadline"`). Also, in order to prevent errors when `deadline` is wrong, you could just add `v-if="deadline"` to your `<flip-countdown>`

Comment: Thanks, the directive  v-if="deadline" it's a good fix. I used two very similar components to have a complete component in just one place. Btw I'll change the names to avoid mistakes.  Using directive v-if I'll remove all computed values. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parent component passes the `deadline`  to its child component before the mounted lifecycle hook fires. Your child component sets its `deadline` with the initial value of undefined.

You should make `deadline` a computed property in child component:

```
computed: {
  internalDeadline() {
    return this.deadline; // comming from props
  }
}
```

Then you can use `internalDeadline` in child.

---

Alternatively, you could wait to render the child component until `deadline` is defined:

```
<flip-countdown v-if="deadline !== undefined" :deadline="deadline"></flip-countdown>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have same issue also moving computed value to child. So I prefer using the v-if directive. Less code. Thanks for help!